# Prism + XF: How to navigate to different view depending on app state

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When I call

`navigationService.NavigateAsync('MyPage')`

depending on the screen resolution, it needs to show the view in different ways:

On large screen it's showing a panel inside the current `Page` (a `ContentView` needs to be created inside the current `ContentPage`), and on small screens it has to navigate to a `Page`

How can I achieve this with Prism?

**EDIT**: The issue I have is actually how to show the view.
On small screen it's navigating to a `Page` like, on big screen it needs to make a `View` visible in current page.

How can I achieve this? Should I create my own navigation service and override `NavigateAsync`? And based on the view name and device idiom, I either navigate to it with default behavior or I show the view in current view:

```
public class MyPageNavigationService : UnityPageNavigationService
{
    public MyPageNavigationService (IUnityContainer container, IApplicationProvider applicationProvider, ILoggerFacade logger)
        : base(container, applicationProvider, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task NavigateAsync(string name, NavigationParameters parameters = null, bool? useModalNavigation = default(bool?), bool animated = true)
    {
        if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            if (name == "TheNextPage")
            {
                 // do custom stuff here, show the view inside current Page
            }
            else
            {
                return base.NavigateAsync(name, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.NavigateAsync(name, parameters, useModalNavigation, animated);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do this without Prism?  You approach doesn't change, though you could take advantage of different Prism features to make it easier to manage.  You could create a module (project) for each device size you want to support.  Then only load the module you want based on the device.  This would allow you to register all the views with the same key, and always navigate to the same key, but depending on which module loaded you would get a different page.  This keeps your ViewModels clean.

Or you could simply use the good'ol

```
if (some screensize)
 _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SmallPage");
else
 _navigationService.NavigateAsync("BiggerPage");
```

I personally would use the module approach.

Comment: Thank you. I can always find "solutions", but only few are correct. Separation by module makes sense but it adds a bit of complexity.

Comment: I would argue that it makes it simple and your code will be much cleaner.  This way you will not need to have logical checks in your code to use a different page.  This will pollute your code base. Using modules, you load only the views you need for a device and nothing else changes. Your VM logic will always navigate to the same View key. Simple.

Comment: One of the issues I have sometimes is the view-models can be reused easily in the scenario where you have a view for small screen and a different view for bigger screen. On the view for small screens, there is a button which navigates to the next screen, but it doesn't exist on the view for big screens, because on big screen the next view sits on same page (it's not even a page, it's a view). This makes the view-model for small screen to have a command which doesn't exist on big screen. In the same time other kind of functionality between small and big screen view-models needs to be shared

Comment: EDIT: "One of the issues I have sometimes is the view-models CANNOT be reused easily"

Comment: Sorry, but I realized that I was going a bit off track. My question was specifically how to deal with navigation. I updated my question. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just create two different Pages, and use Container.RegisterTypeForNavigationOnIdiom method. The it will use the Page you provide based on which Idiom the app is running on.